# Selecting dark parts of a picture with fuzzy border

Tags: gimp

I am struggling with the fuzzy selection tool in gimp - try to make the dark part in the picture black while retaining the dark parts below the light border - any advice how to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: This is probably best asked elsewhere as it is not a programming question but rather a request for expert advice on the gimp program.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the fuzzy selection or the color selection :)

Very often the best way is to use the image itself (or a copy). If I understand you, you want to select the top dark part (which is many shades of grey), but not the bottom one. In practice we want an image where the selected parts are white and the un-selected are black, so

- duplicate the layer
- Color>Desaturate (if the image has colors)
- `Color>Invert`
- `Filters>Blur>Gaussian blur` (around 12px in the image you show). In Gimp 2.10, the median blur can also give interesting results)

[image]

- Use `Threshold` to make the white very white and the black very. Use the threshold value that keeps a continuous black line across the picture
- Bucket fill the lower white part with black (in Gimp 2.10.10 you can use the new `Fill by line art detection` option of the bucket

[image]

- Open the Channels list, right click on any f the R, G or B channels and `Channel to selection`.
- Back to the Layers list, hide or delete the work layer, and select the initial layer to continue.

Using the selection with the Curves tool to set the black and white points on the top part:

[image]